# Wi-Fi connectivity issues after installing Cisco 32-bit VPN client on Windows Vista

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, windows-vista

I have recently uninstalled a previous version of the Cisco VPN client by using the Windows add/remove utility in Control Panel. After that, I reinstalled the most recent version of the Cisco 32-bit VPN Client.

For some reason after this, my wifi has not been working. It says that I have "limited access" to my wifi.

Can someone please tell me how to fix this? It's urgent!! Thanks.

EDIT:

My wifi has been working fine before. I have tried restarting and I have also uninstalled the new version again but the problem persists.

Comment: Did you see if your WiFi was faulty for the in-between time between uninstall and install?  If you installed via network/Internet then the answer is that it was fine.  Does uninstalling the VPN software resolve the issue  (short term)?

Comment: @armani see my edits to the question.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling your WiFi card driver?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post output of `ipconfig /all` and `route print`? For example to pastebin.com and paste links.

What about `ping`? Is `ping` working? If yes it can be DNS. Next you can try `ipconfig /flushdns`, `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew` commands.

Answer (score 0):

Cisco VPN is known to cause similar issues. Chances are that this is just a Cisco VPN or Wi-Fi driver bug. Just go back to the version that used to work.